# expectation of random probability measure

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory

Given $\mu(\omega, B)$ is a random probability measure on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. This means for each $B$, it is a random variable, and for each $\omega$ it is a probability measure.

How could I show that
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu\bigg] =\int_\mathbb{R} f d\mathbb{E}[\mu]$$
where $f$ is a bounded continuous function?

If $f$ is also differentiable, using Fubini theorem, we can rewrite
$$\int_\mathbb{R} f d\mu = \int_0^\infty f d\mu=\int_0^\infty f'(x)\mu(x,\infty) dx.$$
Is there any measurability issue for $\mu(x,\infty)$ when switching the expectation with the integral in the term below
$$\mathbb{E}\bigg[\int_0^\infty f'(x)\mu(x,\infty) dx\bigg]?$$

Answer (score 1):

Measurability is not an issue but your second equality needs justification.

There is a  much simpler way. The required identity is obvious when $f$ is an indicator function. Hence it is true for simple functions, hence for non-negative measurable functions and finally for all functions for which the integrals exist. For bounded continuous functions the integrals do exist.